# Open subsets of surfaces are surfaces

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I'm stuck in a problem of the O'Neill's intro to diff. Geometry (show that for a surface M, $ U \subseteq M$, U is a surface iff U is open):

$\Rightarrow$ Let U be a surface. That means that for every point of U there are proper mappings $\textbf{x} \colon D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, where the image of X, X(D) contains a Neighborhood of p in U and $\textbf{x}^{-1}$ is continuous. My idea here is that, since U is composed of the union of all these patches, and since each patch contains an open set, then U is an open set due to the fact that every arbitrary union of open sets is a set.

$\Leftarrow$ Here, I'm considering some ideas. For this part, let U be an open subset of M. Since M is a surface, the patch existence in M is a guarantee. So, since $\textbf{x}^{-1}$ is continuous, we can obtain a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (I went with U) such that $\textbf{x}^{-1}\vert_{U}$ is continuous. Is that all I have to consider to sketch my final proof?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The $\impliedby$ argument is fine.

But your $\implies$ argument is not complete. It may be true that $X(D)$ is a neighborhood of $p$ in $U$, but for purposes of showing that $U$ is open you need more, you need to show that $X(D)$ is a neighborhood of $p$ in $M$. If you can do that then the rest of the argument is fine.